# Sending a Boolean as a field to another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I saw this question asked some times but no one correlates to mine. I see people using the GetComponent() function but this one should work too.

First I receive a Bool value from a toggle button and assign it as a field of the object 'hydro':

hydroControl.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Assets.Code.PowerPlants;

public class hydroProwerControlPanel : MonoBehaviour {
private HydroElectric hydro;
public bool t1;

void Start () 
{ 
    t1 = true;
}

public hydroProwerControlPanel (){
    hydro = new HydroElectric();
}
public void turbine1State (bool t1) {
     hydro.t1Bool = t1;
}
```

The I have the object where this bool change should be recognized and sent as an output, but it doesn't:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
namespace Assets.Code.PowerPlants
{
    public class HydroElectric
    {
        public bool t1Bool;
        float turbina1;

        public float prod;

        public HydroElectric ()
        {   
          t1Bool = true;
          prod = 0f; 
        }

        public float ControlPanel ()
        {
            turbina1 = t1Bool ? 1.5F : 0;   

            prod = turbina1 ;
            Debug.Log (prod);
            return prod;
        }
    }
}
```

As requested, this is where the function ControlPanel() is called:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Assets.Code.PowerPlants;
namespace Assets.Code.Interfaces
{

public class PlayLevel1 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private HydroElectric hydro;
    public Text producao;

    public PlayLevel1 ()
    {
        hydro = new HydroElectric();
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
     producao.text = hydro.ControlPanel().ToString();          
    }
}
}
```

Do you have any idea why does this Bool does not get updated? Any help appreciated.

Comment: show some more code where did u call controlpanel

Comment: I just did! Please see above.

Comment: my friend PlayLevel1 Hyrdo and hydroProwerControlPanel' hydro object are two distinct instances.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but in your PlayLevel1 class, you are just calling the Hydroelectric and you're not changing any values, so your t1Bool will always be true and therefore the hydro.ControlPanel.ToString() will always return the same value. Should you be calling the turbine1State?? I feel there's something missing in your explaination.

Comment: But that value is changing due to the function turbine1State that receives input from a toggle button.

Comment: if turbine1State changes the bool, that change should be reflected when ControlPanel() is called in the Playlevel1 class. The bool is a field of the class HydroEletric

Answer (score 0):

**PlayLevel1's Hyrdo and hydroProwerControlPanel's hydro object are two different instances**. C*hange in one instance will not reflect the change in second instance* both are independent instances .
The thing you want to achieve is only possible if  you make HydroElectric **static class** with **static members**. 
Hope it will help.

Comment: I am having trouble doing it because I get a ton of errors for making the HydroElectric class static: "cannot declare instance members in a static class"

Comment: I am working it out, it seems making it static changes things a bit.

Comment: i guess you are very new to programming. m right? as i have told you before a static class with static members. all will be static inside static class. This is the reason of your error.

Comment: Yes, I am. I am re-structuring the code to deal with it.